# Get ManyToMany objects

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I'm building a simple application to learn Django.

Basicly a portfolio can have multiple companies in it. I want to display the companies of a certain portfolio of the logged in user.

Models.py

```
class UserPortfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='X')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #Company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='X')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=6, default='X', unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:detail',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

class PortfolioCompany(models.Model):
    UserPortfolio = models.ForeignKey(UserPortfolio)
    Company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

views.py

```
portfolio = UserPortfolio.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        myPortfolioRel = PortfolioCompany.objects.filter(UserPortfolio=portfolio)
```

But now it only displays the ID of the portfolioCompany.

How can I display the Companies inside the UserPortfolio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found it. I need to work the other way around.

```
portfolio = UserPortfolio.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
myPortfolioCompanies = PortfolioCompany.objects.filter(UserPortfolio__in=portfolio)
myCompanies= Company.objects.filter(portfoliocompany__in=myPortfolioCompanies)
```

Comment: I probably dont need PortfolioCompany since thats autocreated, and just attach it (manytomany) to UserPortfolio directly.

Answer (score 0):

Access the many to many field and apply query set filter to it like all or filter or count to use many to many fields.

```
 company = portfolio.Company.all()
```

Applying a query set function is required because it's a many to many field and it's required for serialisation of the data.